# How can you use a Flutter package developed locally as a dependency without having to push the package code every time you make a change?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-packages

I am working on a Flutter app that depends on an internal package where common functionality is extracted.

I have the package as a dependency in the `pubspec.yaml` as follows:

```
dependencies:
  package1:
    git:
      url: git://github.com/myproj/packages.git
      path: packages/package1
```

Everything works fine, but when I have to make a small change in package1, I have to push the code then run `flutter pub upgrade` in my project which takes quite a while.

How can I depend on an internal package and be able to do the development without having to push the code of the package every time?

Answer (score 1):

You can write it as this to use a local package

```
dependencies:
  package1:
    path: ../packages/package1
```

Comment: Thank you! What happens when I deploy the app in production?

Comment: @RăzvanPuiu I guess it would fail then

Comment: I believe the same... I was hoping for a solution that is able to combine both :(

Comment: @RăzvanPuiu I just manually comment it out and switch to the github version of my package before deploy.